# $ Conflict disabling other elements of site

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm creating a web app but have come across a bit of a problem with a bit of coding... the web app has a side menu, much like the facebook one. As well as that it has a enquiry form which is fairly advanced and has dynamic fields which are controlled by .js files. in the form you can select a Category, then a product or service based on that category, once you have selected the field of interest the js files come into action and populates new fields within the form. Now this very file conflicts with my side menu due to the $ symbol i have tried inputting Jquery but had no luck... is there any other method like the JS No Conflict I could wrap this in? It's been killing me for weeks now and I cant seem to overcome it. Here is the code:

```
    function $() {
    var elements = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var element = arguments[i];
        if (typeof element == 'string')
          element = document.getElementById(element);
        if (arguments.length == 1)
          return element;
        elements.push(element);
    }
    return elements;
}
```

Your thoughts regarding this would be much appreciated thank you.

Oh and here is the full .js

```
    //++ Functions for Ajax

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    var xmlHttp=null;
    try
    {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        // Internet Explorer
        try
        {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
function ajaxOnSuccess()
{
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
//--
//++ Function for process element in HTML
function formSerialize(formID)
{
    var f=$(formID);
    var elem = f.elements;
    var flength = elem.length;
    var i = 0;
    var str = "";
    for(i=0;i<flength;i++)
    {
        if(elem[i].type=='radio' || elem[i].type=='checkbox')
        {
            if(elem[i].checked==true)
    {
                if(i<flength-1)
                {
                    str += elem[i].name + "=" + nl2br(elem[i].value) + "&";
                }
                else
                {
                    str += elem[i].name + "=" + nl2br(elem[i].value);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(i<flength-1)
            {
                str += elem[i].name + "=" + nl2br(elem[i].value) + "&";
            }
            else
            {
                str += elem[i].name + "=" + nl2br(elem[i].value);
            }
                }
    }
    //alert(str);
    return str;
}


function $() {
    var elements = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var element = arguments[i];
        if (typeof element == 'string')
          element = document.getElementById(element);
        if (arguments.length == 1)
          return element;
        elements.push(element);
    }
    return elements;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ ?

Comment: Does the function have to be named `$`?

Comment: If I'm honest I'm not sure how to use  jQuery.noConflict its not my area of expertise. I'm more of an editor/adaptor... am trying to learn though. How would I wrap that in the noConflict?

Comment: Dont know what else to name it other than $ Chris Sorry im not much help am i

Comment: @mrmason Well, the problem is that jQuery uses `$` as a short hand for `jQuery`. When you try to give a global function the same name, you will get a conflict. You can prevent jQuery from using `$` by calling  `jQuery.noConflict()` directly after you've loaded the jQuery-library. But if you don't have code that is out of your control, that require your function to be called `$`, I guess the easiest way to solve your problem would be to name the function anything but `$`. Use another character, or even better, a name that describe what it actually does.